# Angular/Rails $resource saving

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

This is the code:

```
  $scope.createAnimator = ->
    console.log($scope.animator.name)
    console.log($scope.animator.description)
    console.log($scope.animator.image)
    $scope.buttonText = "Saving..."
    $scope.animator.$save ->
      $state.go('animators.all')
```

I get the name and description fields from the form, but this is the 'image' field:

```
<img-crop class="ng-isolate-scope" result-image="animator.image" name="image" image="originalImage">
```

When I try to execute `$animator.save` I get all fields in the console - name, description and image.

Rails code:

```
render json: params and return
```

In output rendering I see something like this:

```
{ image: "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0K...", animator: {name: "...", description: "..."}}
```

I don't understand why 'name' and 'description' are in 'animator' group, but 'image' is not? How can I fix it? I need to move 'image' to the 'animator' group!

Comment: `name="animator[image]"`

Comment: Can you maybe show your full form? That might help identify the difference.